# Recover files deleted with rm under msys2

Tags: data-recovery, file-management, rm, msys2

I was using a bash terminal under msys2.
I have accidentally removed some user files with `rm`, under `~/MyDir`.

Do I have any higher chances of recovering them as compared to files removed with `rm` under Linux (which is quite hard)?

What is a possible attempt?

Comment: There isn't enough information here but I would guess that deleted is deleted.  Look into the windows methods for recovering deleted files and DO NOTHING with that volume until you do.  By NOTHING, I mean NOTHING to include using that machine to post these questions if those files are part of your one and only volume that windows is using.

Comment: `removed files in msys2 with rm` is what I am talking about.  removed *other* files via msys2?  By msys2, do you mean a bash console running under msys2?  Removed msys2 files?  Although it might *seem* clear, it isn't to me.  What exactly are you trying to recover?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Please see EDITed OP. I hope I have answered your questions.
You have actually posted 3 explicit questions, and I wasn't sure about all of them.
In particular, "What exactly are you trying to recover?" ... I would say, the files that were `rm`d.

Comment: Under the hood, your bash console is calling the same windows functions as cmd.exe would.  I mean no offense of what you are recovering as that is your business and not mine. :)  I was just trying to make sure that it was something that you produced and not something this might be recovered elsewhere.  I *should have* looked at your 4000+ points before asking this question ;)  .. I would suggest following standard windows procedures.  I myself usually use [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) when in a pinch.